# Adding one more condition for lookup formula on excel

Tags: excel, vba

Based on the formula, there should be 2 conditions. For example I would need to get a value from another table with condition that it was either assigned to Eusebio, Mark or from another user, how can i add the user into the formula. It should be either Eusebio, Mark or Tan, Johnny.

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307, INDEX(Table_owssvr_1[Start Date], MATCH(Table_ACBD_Summary.accdb4[@[Reference Number]]& "Eusebio, Mark" & "WIP",Table_owssvr_1[REF ID]&Table_owssvr_1[Assigned To]&Table_owssvr_1[Status2], 0))), "")`

Answer (score 0):

Is the data you are looking for in the same table, but you need two search criteria (in two different columns)?
Let suppose that we have the following table in Excel:

```
B   C   D   E
2   A   2   7
3   A   3   8
4   B   2   9
5   B   3   10
```

B, C, D, E represent column names, and 2, 3, 4, 5 represent row numbers

Let suppose I am looking for a record (the data I am lookng for is located in column E) that in column C has got "A" and in column D has got "3". In the cell A6 I enter "A" and in the cell B6 I write "3". 
Below I write the following function:
=INDEX(C2:E5,MATCH(1,(C2:C5=A6)*(D2:D5=B6),0),3)
To make this function work, leave the cell with a function by pressing a combination of CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, not ENTER.